# Run script on startup and other script on restart

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell

I am not entire sure this is the right place to ask the question. But here goes.

I have a script that runs fine on startup, that install docker. Afterwards I would like to restart the server and run some more scripts. Is there any way to automate this process?

eg.

> Install A.
>
> restart
>
> Install B and run B

AWS Lighthouse and EC2 has a startup script you can run first time you create new instance. But I would like to run something after Restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a script that runs fine on startup, that installs docker.

If the script "A" is supposed to install only Docker then I will not recommend installing Docker in such a way while working on AWS with docker.

I will recommend using [AWS optimized ECS AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html) that has Docker and everything that need to run from testing to production.

If you launch the instance with Amazon ECS-optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI consists of:

- The latest minimal version of the Amazon Linux 2
- The latest version of the Amazon ECS container agent (1.30.0)
- The recommended version of Docker for the latest Amazon ECS container agent (18.06.1-ce)
- The latest version of the ecs-init package to run and monitor the Amazon ECS agent (1.30.0-1)

I am not sure why do you need to restart the instance after installing A? so in the above AMI, you have docker which you want to on `Script A` so add `Script B` in [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) which will run on boot and you will not need to restart.

If you are still willing to continue with your current approch then its depend upon the underlying OS to run the script on reboot or shut down as only the **user data** behaviour is same for all OS you can also try the posted answer by @Pacifist or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/369872/run-a-bash-script-after-ec2-instance-boots).

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the user data to perform something once your instance has been restarted.

Refer below link to achieve the same :

[Execute user data with every restart](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/)